# Export a Java project without main method (with external jars) to Jar in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have created a java project which only handles post and get request from a web api. I need to export it as jar file. The issue is I'm using external jar files such as httpcore-4.3.3.jar and gson-2.3.1.jar. **I have seen many solution to export as runnable jar**, Since **I don't have any main method** how can I export my utility java project to jar file.

**My issue is I'm unable to export my project which has no main method as JAR along with my library files in eclipse.**

Thanks in Advance

**Edit Update:1**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think having or not having a main method affects how eclipse makes jars.  Are you asking how to export a jar for a program which uses other jars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used [Fat Jar](http://kurucz-grafika.de/fatjar) to export My Java project as JAR along with my referenced libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Export it as a normal JAR file:

```
Export -> Java -> JAR File
```

Comment: Yes, but how to export as jar with the library files which you have used??

Comment: Then you will need either Ant or Maven to do it.

Comment: Can you point me somewhere a blog or documentation on how to do this in eclipse..

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html and http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-81_basics.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use export to "Jar File", not "Runnable Jar File"

A "Runnable Jar File" is a jar file with manifest pointing to the the class containing a main method.
It allows to run a java application by just calling:

> java -jar <your jar file>

instead of

> java -cp <your jar file> <your class with main method>

Obviously exporting to runnable jar file does not work if you don't have at least one class with a main method.

Comment: My issue is I'm unable to export my project which has no main method as JAR along with my library files in eclipse.